# How to save a value to a @OneToMany field in a Spring + Hibernate + JSP applicatication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a Spring + Hibernate + JSP based app, and one of the entities (Invoice) contains a @OneToMany field (InvoiceItems), which is present in the entity object as a List type member.

From the JSP page, i would like to insert a new Invoice along with several values in this field (more InvoiceItems). But I have no idea, how could i reference this on the JSP. 
I tried

```
<form:input path="invoiceItems[0].unitPrice" />
```

but this doesn't load up the @ModelAttribute object's (Invoice) invoiceItems field with the appropriate unitPrice value.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Solution is to use
    spring:bind
tags around the input fields to be mapped

Comment: http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-crud-example.html

Comment: you should look on spring custom data binder, it can convert you string to collection (tags for example) or your fields values to collection.